# Access SQL - Where multiple dates match

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, match

I have the following Access table called 'Products'

```
REF         DATE               DAYS
12345       26/03/2020         55
12345       26/03/2020         55
12345       20/03/2020         50
12345       30/06/2020        100
98765       05/02/2020         70
98765       05/02/2020         70
98765       10/04/2020         91
```

I need to create an SQL query in Access that gives an output where each unique REF is listed and then a YES/NO column. The result is YES if all of the DATE values are the same date for the records where DAYS is <= 90 days. If any of the dates are different for the records where DAYS <= 90 then the output should be NO.

I'm not interested in any dates where the value of DAYS is greater than 90.

For the above example, the output would be:

```
REF       SAME_DATE
12345     No
98765     Yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access, you can use aggregation to calculate the flag and then a `JOIN`:

```
select p.*, nz(flag, 'NO')
from products as p left join
     (select pp.ref, 'YES' as flag
      from products as pp
      where p2.days <= 90
      group by pp.ref
      having min(date) = max(date)
     ) as pp
     on pp.ref = p.ref;
```

EDIT:

If you want one row per ref, this is much easier:

```
select ref,   
       iif(min(date) = max(date), "Yes", "No") as same_date
from products
where days <= 90
group by ref;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, tried this but it's returning every record, rather than a unique per REF. Also every 'flag' is YES. I noticed your WHERE p2.days <= 90 refers to 'p2' which isn't defined so I think that should be pp.days <= 90?

Comment: @markthornton90 . . . I added the version with one row per `ref`.